# Not able to read from serialize file

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

In below code i am writing file contents in backup serialize file through boost serialization library, but what i observed that every time i need to store all the data in file then only i would be able to read the entire data.
so in case if i don't perform the write operation and just try to get the store data in backup file then not able to read anything stored in backup file.
After executing entire code i am able to read the serialize map from file but while performing read operation only without write not able to read anything.
below is the commented code snippet for write operation. please suggest if there is something wrong in the code .

### commented portion of the code of writefile Api

```
 /*obj.writefile("wasim",23);
    obj.writefile("available",12);
    obj.writefile("jack",32);
    obj.writefile("john",37);
    obj.writefile("hate",11);
    obj.writefile("kk",37);*/
    obj.writefile("abc",39); 
    obj.readfile();
    ret_value=obj.parse_map();
    cout<<ret_value;
```

### Entire code snippet:

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
using namespace std;
enum RESULT_T
            {

            ret_error   =-1,
            ret_success = 0

            } ;


class object_model
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & mymap;

    }

    map<string,int> mymap;



public:
         object_model(){

     };

     void writefile (string key,int value);
     map<string, int> readfile();
     RESULT_T parse_map();
     int deserialize_validation();

};



 RESULT_T object_model::parse_map()
{

    auto new_map = readfile();
    for (auto itr: new_map)
               {

                cout<<itr.first <<":"<<itr.second<<endl;

               }

return ret_success;
}
void object_model::writefile( string key, int value)
{

    mymap[key] = value;
    std::ofstream ss("backup",ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarch(ss);
    oarch << mymap;

}


map<string, int>  object_model::readfile()
{
    std::map<string,int> new_map;
       {
       std::ifstream ifs("backup",ios::binary);
       boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
       ia >> new_map;
       }

       return new_map;


}
int main()
{
    RESULT_T ret_value;
    object_model obj;
    obj.writefile("hate",11);
    obj.writefile("wasim",23);
    obj.writefile("available",12);
    obj.writefile("jack",32);
    obj.writefile("john",37);
    obj.writefile("kk",37);

    obj.readfile();
    ret_value=obj.parse_map();
    cout<<ret_value;
    }
```

Comment: why you have mix of C++ and boost headers

Comment: I just started working on boost  wasn't aware about STL map and vector compatibility with boost.

Comment: "but while performing read operation only without write not able to read anything" - wouldn't that simply mean the file doesn't exist yet?

Comment: file is already exist but not able to read the old data so whenever write operation happens read operation is able to read that particular data only but ignores the old data previously written in the file.

Comment: it look like append issue as i can see that old content is omitted and new contents only written . ios::app mode will have appended contents in file but while reading only recently written contents can be read